# Monitor JVM CPU/RAM usage by java

Tags: java, tomcat, monitoring, jmx

i use JMX to get JVM utilization (CPU , memory , Threads...) and appear result on Jconsole ,
but i need API to integrate with Java code
and get utilization of tomcat then log the data into file
Is there API technology or service in windows using from command line do that?

Comment: Your Question is not clear, not specific. FYI, [Tomcat provides JMX hooks.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/monitoring.html)

Answer (score 2):

JMX is a technology designed to be used by Java programs, so yes, this is possible. You’ll want to create a JMX Service URL to point to the server (presumably on localhost) and then connect it with a JMX Connector:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
```

Once you’ve got that, you can then get MBeans by name,

```
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

From there you can get the MBean, including things that are reported in the jconsole. For example, with `RuntimeMXBean`:

```
RuntimeMXBean proxy = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
  mbsc,
  ManagementFactory.RUNTIME_MXBEAN_NAME,
  RuntimeMXBean.class);
long uptime = proxy.getUptime();
```

If you want to inspect memory, you'll need to find out the memory pools available, then iterate through each. You can also set up a listener to look out for changes.
See the tutorial for more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html